# finding all possible subsets of a dataframe

Tags: r

I am looking for a function that takes a column of a data.frame as the reference and finds all subsets with respect to the other variable levels. For example, let `z` be data frame with 4 columns `a,b,c,d`, each column has 2 levels for instance. let `a` be the reference. Then z would be like

```
z$a : TRUE FALSE
z$b : TRUE FALSE
z$c : TRUE FALSE
z$d : TRUE FALSE
```

Then what I need is a LIST that the elements are combination names such as

```
aTRUEbTRUEcTRUEdTR UE :subset of the dataframe 
aTRUEbFALSEcTRUEdTRUE : subset
...
```

Here is an example,

```
set.seed(123)
z=matrix(sample(c(TRUE,FALSE),size = 100,replace = TRUE),ncol=4)
colnames(z) = letters[1:4]
z=as.data.frame(z)


output= list(
    'bTUEcTRUEdFALSE' = subset(z,b==TRUE & c==TRUE & d==FALSE),
    'bTRUEcTRUEdTRUE' = subset(z,b==TRUE & c==TRUE & d==TRUE),
    'bTRUEcFALSEdFALSE' = subset(z,b==TRUE & c==FALSE & d==FALSE),
    'bTRUEcFALSEdTRUE' = subset(z,b==TRUE & c==FALSE & d==TRUE)
    # and so on ...
)
output
$bTUEcTRUEdFALSE
       a    b    c     d
13 FALSE TRUE TRUE FALSE
14 FALSE TRUE TRUE FALSE

$bTRUEcTRUEdTRUE
       a    b    c    d
4  FALSE TRUE TRUE TRUE
10  TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
16 FALSE TRUE TRUE TRUE
20 FALSE TRUE TRUE TRUE
24 FALSE TRUE TRUE TRUE

$bTRUEcFALSEdFALSE
       a    b     c     d
17  TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE
19  TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE
22 FALSE TRUE FALSE FALSE

$bTRUEcFALSEdTRUE
       a    b     c    d
5  FALSE TRUE FALSE TRUE
11 FALSE TRUE FALSE TRUE
15  TRUE TRUE FALSE TRUE
18  TRUE TRUE FALSE TRUE
21 FALSE TRUE FALSE TRUE
23 FALSE TRUE FALSE TRUE
```

However, there is an issue with the example. firstly, I do not know the number of variables (in this case 4 (a to d). Secondly, the name of the variables must be caught from the data (simple speaking, I cannot use subset since I do not know the variable name in the condition (a== can be anything==)

What is the most efficient way of doing this in R?

Comment: Unclear. Please provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269) and expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `split` and `paste` like so:

```
split(z, paste(z$b, z$c, z$d))
```

But the tricky part of your question is how to programmatically combine the variables in columns 2:end without knowing beforehand the number of columns, their names or values. We can use a function like below to paste the values by row in columns 2:end

```
apply(df, 1, function(i) paste(i[-1], collapse=""))
```

Now combine with `split`

```
split(z, apply(z, 1, function(i) paste(i[-1], collapse="")))
```